# cxf client Java HttpURLConnection and pooling

Tags: java, https, cxf

The cxf client sends a request to the server through Https，
can i reuse the socket link？

I already set the following parameters：

http.maxConnections=200.

http.keepalive=true.

it doesn't work
because this method parm var2 always different,var1 have same host and port .
var2 always be different SSLSocketFactory.

**sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache#put(URL var1, Object var2, HttpClient var3)**

how can i make connection reuse ？

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.